# Can one copy of Windows 7 Upgrade work on two computers?

Tags: windows, upgrade

I've got two computers running windows vista. If I buy Windows 7 Professional Upgrade, can I upgrade both computers? Or will I need two copies of Windows 7 Professional Upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yepp you will need two. (You can get a "pack" of upgrades I guess, check the web for more information on this. Like the "family pack" from Windows7.)

(One key, one PC is the key word. Except if that is a MSDN key.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a different license for each computer; once a license key is activated, it would not work for the 2nd machine.

Answer (score 1):

One copy of the upgrade *will* work, but you will not be acting in accordance with the licence agreement between you and Microsoft.

It would be like you and your twin sharing a driving licence - you will look similar enough to get away with it, but it is still wrong.

Comment: Hmm the latest WPA update won't kill this method? (I heard about it but never tried)

Comment: @Shiki - Yup, believe Windows to go to reduced functionality mode.